# scikit-learn HDBscan throws error when trying to compute medoids/centroids

Tags: python, scikit-learn, centroid, hdbscan

I have a precomputed distance matrix that I want to find the medoids for. According to the [scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.HDBSCAN.html), there's a parameter and attribute that you have to set and call in order to retrieve these medoids. When I set the parameter `store_centers="medoid"` and call the attribute `.medoids_` I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Clustering\Model.py", line 163, in <module>
    cluster(df, 'test.txt')
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Clustering\Model.py", line 139, in cluster
    clustering = hdb.fit(distance_matrix.tocsr())
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Clustering\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_hdbscan\hdbscan.py", line 854, in fit
    self._weighted_cluster_center(X)
 in _weighted_cluster_center
    dist_mat = pairwise_distances(
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Clustering\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 2157, in pairwise_distances
    X, _ = check_pairwise_arrays(
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Clustering\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 184, in check_pairwise_arrays
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Precomputed metric requires shape (n_queries, n_indexed). Got (9, 2292) for 9 indexed.
```

I'm unsure as to how my square precomputed matrix is producing a 9x2292 array. Otherwise, the model works fine and I have no issues manually retrieving the medoids through a mse operation. The reason I want to produce the medoid's this way is in hopes of finding the variable eps for each cluster so that I can fit more data to the clusters.

EDIT:
My Code with nonreproducible example:

````
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from sklearn.cluster import HDBSCAN
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
import itertools

def dis_matrix(word_list):
    count = 0
    kw_index = {}
    index_kw = {}
    n = len(word_list)
    distance_matrix = lil_matrix((n, n))

    for kw in word_list:
        kw_index[kw] = count
        index_kw[count] = kw
        count += 1

    for x, y in itertools.product(word_list,word_list):
        d = fuzz.ratio(x,y) / 100
        distance = 1 - d if d <= 1 else 0.00000000000001
        index1 = kw_index[x]
        index2 = kw_index[y]
        distance_matrix[index1, index2] = distance
        distance_matrix[index2, index1] = distance

    return distance_matrix, index_kw

CLUSTERING_MIN_SAMPLES = 2
x = ['apple', 'app', 'banana', 'bannana', 'applesauce', 'peaches', 'peach', "appban"]
distance_matrix, index_kw = dis_matrix(x)
hdb = HDBSCAN(cluster_selection_epsilon=.1, metric='precomputed', n_jobs=8, min_samples=CLUSTERING_MIN_SAMPLES,store_centers='medoid')
clustering = hdb.fit(distance_matrix.tocsr())
print(clustering.medoids_)```
````

Comment: Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: @doneforaiur Question has been updated. Please see above

Comment: @doneforaiur I can't provide my actual data and unfortunately this result does produce the list of medoids. Is there any way you can piece the answer to my question by just looking at my code and the error message I receive? When using my actual data I produce a 15,000x15,000 distance matrix

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/190) issue?